# React Native won't recognize the Android SDK

Tags: android, react-native

I have a React Native application, that runs fine on iOS, I tried to run it on Android too, but I always get the error:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 116691 > 65536 ; # fields: 80012 > 65536)
```

I tried every solution I saw, nothing worked.

I ran the `react-native-community cli doctor` and it seems like React Native won't recognize the Android SDK.
I checked, and the `emulator sdk` and the `gradle sdk` versions are the same.
echoing `ANDROID_HOME` on the terminal properly gives me the sdk path, I followed the React Native getting started again to see if I missed something, but it seems like everything is install correctly.

I can't figure out why this won't run.

Comment: Have you tested a “hello world” apps a sanity check? The complaint about class size means it appears to be trying to run.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, I have the application running great on iOS, on Android I can't run it. I also tried to run native Android application, to check if everything really installed properly, I have no problem running a native app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `android\app\build.gradle` try adding

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
   }
}
```